# Can't read arabic string / client server application c#

Tags: c#

I am coding clients/server application  and everything working fine in english language but when I send a message in arabic it came with string chars. 
I don't know what I can do to make arabic message work fine like english language.

Thanks in advance!

```
 public Packet(byte[] dataStream)
 {
    // Read the data identifier from the beginning of the stream (4 bytes)

    this.dataIdentifier = (DataIdentifier)BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 0);

    // Read the length of the name (4 bytes)
    int nameLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 4);

    // Read the length of the message (4 bytes)
    int msgLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataStream, 8);

    // Read the name field
    if (nameLength > 0)
        this.name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12, nameLength);
    else
        this.name = null;

    // Read the message field
    if (msgLength > 0)
        this.message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataStream, 12 + nameLength, msgLength);
    else
        this.message = null;
}

// Converts the packet into a byte array for sending/receiving 
public byte[] GetDataStream()
{
    List<byte> dataStream = new List<byte>();

    // Add the dataIdentifier
    dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)this.dataIdentifier));

    // Add the name length
    if (this.name != null)
        dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.name.Length));
    else
        dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

    // Add the message length
    if (this.message != null)
        dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(this.message.Length));
    else
        dataStream.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(0));

    // Add the name
    if (this.name != null)
        dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.name));

    // Add the message
    if (this.message != null)
        dataStream.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.message));

    return dataStream.ToArray();
}

// Initialise a packet object to store the data to be sent
Packet sendData = new Packet();
sendData.ChatName = this.name;

sendData.ChatMessage =  txtMessage.Text.Trim();

sendData.ChatDataIdentifier = DataIdentifier.Message;

// Get packet as byte array
byte[] byteData = sendData.GetDataStream();

// Send packet to the server
clientSocket.BeginSendTo(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, epServer, new AsyncCallback(this.SendData), null);

txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: are you sure its UTF8 and not an arabic codepage? who sends the data?

Comment: You encode the string length, but not the number of UTF8 bytes of each string. These values may be the same for ASCII characters, but certainly not for characters outside ASCII, such as Arabic